# Spring mvc - Configuring Error handling for XML and JSON Response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

i have one REST API method :which will return Xml as response . Just for simplicity assume it throws simple Exception.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "machine/xmlData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getXml(HttpServletRequest request)
            throws Exception {
        return getDataFromService();

}
```

Now i am handling the Exception in REST Controller like this.
This is generic Exception Handle method, for other API methods as well.(Xml or JSON Response)

```
 @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        public ResponseEntity HandleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
           // here logic to generate Custom error Object
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(customErrorObject, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
```

**Case 1:** Accept :"application/xml" and valid Response from Service
             Everything works fine.

**Case 2:** Accept :"application/xml" and Exception  from Service
             then i get **`406 Not Representable`**

As per my understanding it is

> because ResponseEntity from HandleException is JSON and accept header
>   is "application/xml" thats why i am getting 406.

Is there anyway that i can send the error **Response from HandleException method  as xml and json**  ?
I know on REST API methods  we can define something like this  `produces={"application/json","application/xml"}` i am struggling to  put this on HandleException Method.

Any tip would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: remove @ResponseStatus in handleException and try

Comment: @kuhajeyan it does not help . i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the spring-mvc HttpMessageConverters by using the @ResponseBody annotation( https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc). This annotation is responsible for choosing the correct messageConverter for a given response type.

For your response to be xml or json compatible you need to do the following:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WrappedExceptionResponse {
    public String respone;

    public String getRespone() {
        return respone;
    }

    public void setRespone(String respone) {
        this.respone = respone;
    }
}
```

And change your exception handler method to

```
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public @ResponseBody WrappedExceptionResponse HandleException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
//        ex.printStackTrace();
       // here logic to generate Custom error Object
        WrappedExceptionResponse resp=new WrappedExceptionResponse();
        resp.setRespone(ex.getMessage());
    return resp;
```

And then your exception response would be dependent on the content-type you give.

Comment: but then its static , i cant use it for JSON MediaTypes. I would like to have some Generic Error Response.

Comment: Eddited my answer please check if it works as expected for both json and xml .

Comment: it does not help.  @ResponseBody is not automatically using the right convertor.

Comment: If you change your rest endpoint to @RequestMapping(value = "machine/xmlData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/xml","application/json"}). Then the response type would be different  with headers like Accept:application/json or Accept:application/xml. The response type is closely related to your Accept header for get requests.

Comment: Adding jackson xml dependency helped.

Comment: How to do the same for Spring >= 5.1? According to the documentation: "Content Negotiation for Error Responses The produces condition of an @RequestMapping no longer impacts the content type of error responses".

Comment: If you use ResponseEntity as a wrapper for your returning type, i think it should  work