# Return content type for Error Responses based on produces condition of @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have custom errors handling in my REST webservice. I have methods returning XML / JSON as response. Everything worked fine on SpringBoot version **2.0.9**. But after migration to latest (**2.2.4**) my error handling tests fail:

```
Content type expected:<application/xml> but was:<application/json>
Expected :application/xml
Actual   :application/json
```

After research I found that it's related with **upgrading Spring to Version 5.1**. Docs:

> Content Negotiation for Error Responses
>   The produces condition of an @RequestMapping no longer impacts the content type of error responses.

How can I reproduce behavior from earlier versions of Spring in the latest? I just want to return the content type for errors as specified in **produces** condition.

Rest methods:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/{scriptName}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Object> xmlMethod(@RequestParam("payload") String payload, @PathVariable("scriptName") String scriptName) {

    Object result = service.call(payload, scriptName);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonBuilder(result).getContent());
}

@PostMapping(path = "/{scriptName}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Object> jsonMethod(@RequestParam("payload") String payload, @PathVariable("scriptName") String scriptName) {
    Object result = service.call(payload, scriptName);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonBuilder(result).getContent());
}
```

CustomRestExceptionHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomRestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {

        HTTPErrorDTO httpError = new HTTPErrorDTO(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(httpError, new HttpHeaders(), httpError.getStatus());
    }

    ....
    // handlers for other exceptions
}
```

Error DTO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Exception")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HTTPErrorDTO {

    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;
    private List<String> errors;
}
```

Related topic: [Spring mvc - Configuring Error handling for XML and JSON Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971714/spring-mvc-configuring-error-handling-for-xml-and-json-response)

**---EDIT**

I tried to add custom content negotiation configuration. But one of clients of my REST API send me content-type = **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** and expect application/xml and don't send any accept headers.

So I can only decide what format the content type should be at the method/controller level.

Can I somehow inform exception handler from controller, which one
content type should be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `HandlerMethod` object to an exception handler method (i.e. `handleResourceNotFoundException` in your question).

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleResourceNotFoundException(
    ResourceNotFoundException ex, 
    WebRequest request, 
    HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
    ........        
}
```

The `HandlerMethod` object represents the controller method that raised the exception. So you can get values of `produces` from an `@RequestMapping` annotation on the object.

```
RequestMapping requestMapping = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
String[] produces = requestMapping.produces();
....
```

In your source code of the question, `produces` is an array that has an element (i.e. `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE` or `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`).

**See Also**
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler-args

Answer (score 1):

In your `CustomRestExceptionHandler`, you can set a media type for the `ResponseEntity`.

```java
return ResponseEntity.status(httpError.getStatus().value())
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .body(httpError);
```

Comment: OK, but I want to support both JSON and XML. Can I somehow inform exception handler from controller, which one content type should be set?

Comment: @Bakus123 `WebRequest` will give you access to the HTTP headers from the request.

Comment: Yes, I know but I do not want to decide based on request header. I would like to specify that from the controller X, errors are always XML, and from Y are JSON.

Comment: @Bakus123 In this case, you can rewrite your exception handler method to accept a `HandlerMethod` parameter.